# (ML.NET) How to train a dataset that doesn't contain labels

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

For a webshop I want to create a model that gives recommendations based on what is on someone's wishlist: a "someone who has X on their wishlist we also recommend Y" scenario. The issue is that the trainers don't work due to a lack of proper Labels which I do not have in my dataset or a lack of enough data altogether. This results in either inaccurate data or prediction scores of float.NAN (either all or most scores end up like this)

At my disposal I have all existing wishlists with the subsequent ProfileId and ItemId's (both are integers). These are grouped in ProfileID-ItemID combinations (representing an item on a wishlist, so a user with 3 items will have 3 combinations). In total, there are around 150.000 combinations I can work with for 16.000 users and 50.000 items. Items that only appear on a single wishlist (or not at all) or users with only one item on their wishlist are excluded from the training data (the above numbers are already filtered). If I want to, I could add extra columns of data representing the category an item is a part of (toys, books, etc.), prices and other metadata.

What I do not have are ratings, since the webshop doesn't use those. Therefore, I cannot use them to represent the "Label"

```cs
public class WishlistItem
{
    // these variables are either uint32 or a Single (float) based on the training algorithm.
    public uint ProfileId;
    public uint ItemId; 
    public float Label;
}
```

**What I expect I need to fix the issue:**

A combination or either of the three:

1) that I need to use a different trainer. If so, which would be best suited?

2) that I need to insert different values for the Label variable. If so, how should it be generated?

3) that I need to generate different 'fake' dataset to pad the trainingdata. If so, how should it be generated?

**Explanation of the problem and failed attempts to remedy it**

I have tried to parse the data using different trainers to see what would work best for my dataset: the *FieldAwareFactorizationMachine*,  the *MatrixFactorizationMachine* and the *OLSTrainer*. I've also tried to use the *MatrixFactorizationMachine* for *LossFunctionType.SquareLossOneClass*, where rather than a ProfileID-ItemID combination combinations of ItemIds on a Wishlist are inserted. (eg. item1-item2, item2-item3, item1-item3 from a wishlist where 3 items are present)

The machines are based on information found in their subsequent tutorials:

- FieldAware: https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/machine-learning-with-ml-net-in-uwp-field-aware-factorization-machine/
- MatrixFactorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/movie-recommendation
- MatrixFactorization (OneClass): https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/build-a-product-recommender-using-c-and-ml-net-machine-learning-ab890b802d25
- OLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.mklcomponentscatalog.ols?view=ml-dotnet

Here is an example of one of the pipelines, the others are very similar:

```c#
string profileEncoded = nameof(WishlistItem.ProfileId) + "Encoded";
string itemEncoded = nameof(WishlistItem.ItemId) + "Encoded";
// the Matrix Factorization pipeline
  var options = new MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options {
                MatrixColumnIndexColumnName = profileEncoded,
                MatrixRowIndexColumnName = itemEncoded,
                LabelColumnName = nameof(WishlistItem.Label),
                NumberOfIterations = 100,
                ApproximationRank = 100
            };

            trainerEstimator = Context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: profileEncoded, inputColumnName: nameof(WishlistItem.ProfileId))
                       .Append(Context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: itemEncoded, inputColumnName: nameof(WishlistItem.ItemId)))
                            .Append(Context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FieldAwareFactorizationMachine(new string[] { "Features" }));
```

In order to mitigate the issue of lacking labels, I've tried several workarounds:

- leaving them blank (a 0f float value)
- using the hashcodes of the itemid, profileid or a combination of both
- counting the amount of items a specific itemid or profileid is included, also manipulating that figure to create less extreme values in case an item is represented hundreds of times. (using square root or a log function, creating `Label = Math.Log(amountoftimes);` or `Label = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(amountoftimes)`
- for the FieldAware machine, where the Label is a Boolean rather than a Float, the calculation above is used to determine whether the float result is above the average of below the average for all items

When testing, I test using the following of 2 possible methods to determine what recommendations "*Y*" can be created for Item "*X*":

- compare ItemID *X* to all existing items, with the ProfileID of the user.

```cs
List<WishlistItem> predictionsForUser =  profileMatrix.DistinctBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => new WishlistItem(userId, x.GiftId, x.Label));

IDataView transformed = trainedModel.Transform(Context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(predictionsForUser));

CoPurchasePrediction[] predictions = Context.Data.CreateEnumerable<CoPurchasePrediction>(transformed, false).ToArray();

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<WishlistItem, CoPurchasePrediction>> results = Enumerable.Range(0, predictions.Length).ToDictionary(x => predictionsForUser[x], x => predictions[x]).Where(x => OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Score).Take(10);


return results.Select(x => x.Key.GiftId.ToString()).ToArray();
```

- Compare the ItemID *X* to items on other people's wishlists where *X* is also present. This one is used for the FieldAware Factorization Trainer, which uses a Boolean as Label.

```cs
public IEnumerable<WishlistItem> CreatePredictDataForUser(string userId, IEnumerable<WishlistItem> userItems)
{
    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<WishlistItem>> giftIdGroups = profileMatrix.GroupBy(x => x.GiftId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y));
    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<WishlistItem>> profileIdGroup = profileMatrix.GroupBy(x => x.ProfileId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y));
            profileIdGroup.Add(userId, userItems);

    List<WishlistItem> results = new List<WishlistItem>();

    foreach (WishlistItem wi in userItems)
    {
       IEnumerable<WishlistItem> giftIdGroup = giftIdGroups[wi.GiftId];
       foreach(WishlistItem subwi in giftIdGroup)
       {
           results.AddRange(profileIdGroup[subwi.ProfileId]);
       }
    }

   IEnumerable<WishlistItem> filtered = results.ExceptBy(userItems, x => x.GiftId);

   // get duplicates
   Dictionary<string, float> duplicates = filtered.GroupBy(x => x.GiftId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => giftLabelValues[x.First().GiftId]);
            float max = duplicates.Values.Max();

    return filtered.DistinctBy(x => x.GiftId).Select(x => new WishlistItem(userId, x.GiftId, duplicates[x.GiftId] * 2 > max));
}
```

However, the testing data remains either completely or partially unusable (float.NAN), or creates always the same recommendation results (*we recommend Y and Z for item X*) regardless of the item inserted.

When evaluating the data using a testdataview (`DataOperationsCatalog.TrainTestData split = Context.Data.TrainTestSplit(data, 0.2)`) It either shows promising results with high accuracy or a random value all over the place, and it doesn't add up with the results I'm getting; high accuracy still results in float.NAN or 'always the same'

Online it is pointed out that float.NAN may be the result of a small dataset. to compensate, I have tried creating 'fake' datasets; profile-item combinations (with label 0f or false, while the rest is 0f+ or true) that are randomly generated based on existing profileid's and itemid's. (It is checked beforehand to rule out that these random 'negative' data isn't also a 'real' combinationset on accident). However, this has shown little to no effect.

Comment: If you don't have labels then I don't believe any of the supervised machine learning algorithms will be of any use. Try one of the unsupervised algorithms such as clustering with KMeans.

Comment: KMeans doesn't appear to be it - if I create a trainer and feed it profile-item combinations and create (amountofitems / 100) clusters, then it still always returns the exact same data regardless of the item. Are there any other unsupervised learning algorithms for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any of the solutions you have tried will work, as, as you have pointed out, you do not have any label data. Faking the label data will not work either as the ML algorithm will work with this faked label.

What I believe you are looking for is a One-Class Matrix Factorization algorithm.

Your "label" or "score" is implicit - the fact that the item is in the user's wishlist itself indicates the label - that the user has an interest in the item. The One-Class Matrix Factorization uses this kind of implicit labelling.

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/890/1*VBLIDo9Us7Cur-xPe-aFxQ.png]

Have a read through this article:
https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/build-a-product-recommender-using-c-and-ml-net-machine-learning-ab890b802d25

Comment: Good answer. I think this is one of the official posts on how to accomplish this as well: [Single Class Matrix Factorization Sample](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_ProductRecommendation)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a classic recommender system solution. Recommender systems are accustomed to missing and sparse data. There are many approaches to solve this problem, and I recommend starting with this [article](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~atuzhili/pdf/TKDE-Paper-as-Printed.pdf). Generally, there are two approaches in recommender systems - model-based and memory-based. In my experience, model-based methods perform much better than memory-based ones. There's a nice summary [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-recommender-systems-6c66cf15ada) regarding the different models and solutions. Look at the matrix factorization solution by Koren and Bell [here](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf) which works very well in many cases.

Comment: I have been using all the system you've suggested before I made this post; the Recommendation Engines of ML.NET predict one item at a time (which would be too time consuming, even when done in paralell), so the Model.Transform function does a number of predictions at once, hence why that is used.  The second article talks mostly about user-item matrixes, which I have been using. The last one talks Latent Factor approach and the User-Oriented Neighborhood method, which I've used also (see the secton on testing, where the algorithms for them are outlined)